# Build a module - maven

Tags: java, maven, github

I'm new to maven and I want to build this [repository](https://github.com/wizardjedi/smpp-test-tools) and then I want only to execute smpp-multiplexer module only on centos.

I know it's a newbie question but if someone can redirect me to the right path it will be appreciated.

Here's the pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.a1systems</groupId>
  <artifactId>smpp-test-tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>smpp-test-tools</name>
    <modules>
        <module>defcode_recognizer</module>
        <module>smpp_cli_pusher</module>
        <module>range_slicer</module>
        <module>http-adapter</module>
        <module>smpp-simulator</module>
        <module>smpp-zabbix-checker</module>
        <module>smpp-multiplexer</module>
        <module>log-watcher</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

if there's a possibility to build only `smpp-multiplexer` it will be better.

Thank you.

Comment: Do a `mvn install` from root location and afterwards you can simply do a `mvn -pl smpp-multiplexer clean package` from root which will build only that single module. You can add options like `--also-make-dependents` which will also build modules which are depending on the given module (`-amd`)...http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-embedder/cli.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the folder `smpp-multiplexer` and execute `mvn install`

Comment: thank you, that did the trick, but when I execute the jar file i got "Could not find or load main class smpp-multiplexer.jar", any idea ?